# Disable all ECDHE cipher in various apache server and IIS server

Tags: windows, apache, iis, redhat

I have various version of apache server and IIS server , the ECDHE cipher is enabled , now I would like to disable it for some reason , would advise how to it ?

Thanks

Comment: Set your ciphers (and order) in the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002

Answer (score 0):

For apache your should modify the following file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

For example we are not selecting two ECDHE suites (note ! before those) in TLS1.1:

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.1

SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!aNULL:!MD5

SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```